# UIWebView ScrollView: Zoom allowed on only piece of webpage

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I only want to show a portion of a webpage in the app -- which I have working. The initial zoom is correct and the position is correct.

The problem is when I go to zoom in or zoom out -- other parts of the webpage which I don't want to show -- show up.

Is there any way to set a boundary to where zooming is allowed? I have a UIWebView which contains a scrollview. I don't want to disable zooming altogether since I want the user to be able to zoom into text that they see in that portion of the webpage.

I had an image but it looks like it won't allow me to upload it. So here is a basic idea:

---------- WEB PAGE -------------

```
    --- SECTION SHOWN ----





    ----------------------
```

--------- END OF WEB PAGE ------

Only allow zooming to the section that is shown in app - anything outside of section shown I don't want the app to even see or get to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried modifying the HTML as it arrives to you (or modifying it with javascript after it has loaded) to remove the content you don't want the user to ever see?

Comment: @IanMacDonald No, I haven't tried that. I'm new to iOS development.

Comment: @IanMacDonald : I realized that what I didn't want displayed is mostly contained inside the 'header' tag. So, I'm able to get the header information by doing this:


`NSString *js = @"var headerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].outerHTML";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
`


However, I haven't had any luck at removing it from the web view using javascript. Any ideas? I've tried using .remove()

Comment: @IanMacDonald I was able to figure out how to remove the content that I wanted -- however, this still doesn't fix my zooming issue. 

removed content by doing:
`NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"var element = document.getElementById('%@'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);",
                          @"nameOftagID", nil];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];`


When I go to zoom in, there is a huge white section where the old content used to be and so it zooms into that.